# iPhone 11 Pro triple lens jumpy zoom

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I tried AVFoundation code to select triple lens and zoom. The problem is zoom is jumpy at about 2x factor around when the camera lens changes. This is also seen in native camera app on iPhone 11 Pro by Apple. The dual camera does not have any such issues. Wondering what is the point in jumpy zoom when the main aim of triple lens is smooth transition between lenses during zoom. Is there anything to fix it?

Here is YouTube video demonstrating the issue:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79e9Sl6nXEw

Comment: Let's hope it will be fixed in the 13.1 update, due in a day or two.

Comment: I am already running iOS 13.1!

Comment: Not beta? Have you got the auto update already?

Comment: Yes, it's out already if you are not aware.

Comment: I know it's there, but it does not unroll immediately to all devices

Comment: https://www.macrumors.com/2019/09/30/apple-releases-ios-13-1-2/

Comment: Doesn't help. I think it's nature of the camera's autofocus systems.

Comment: “the dual camera" you mean iPhone X?